# Remove first element from SortedSet c#

Tags: c#, sortedset

I have a `SortedSet` of custom objects and I want to remove the first element, which I take it with `First()` function from the `SortedSet` collection. The problem is that it doesn't work.

Any help?

[edit] My code:

```
URL u = Queue.First();
Queue.Remove(u);
```

where URL is a custom class.

Comment: How are you trying to remove it? Post that code please.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? You do know that the `First` extension method retrieves a reference but doesn't remove items from enumerables, right?

Comment: @spender - Sorted sets do have an order.

Comment: The problem was in my custom class. Basically when I implemented IComparable I forgotten the equality, and that's why the remove didn't worked out for me... anyway, on the future I will explain better my questions.

Comment: OP's problem is really about the implementation of his custom class. Perhaps the info here is what he needed (as I did): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220369/sortedset-not-using-custom-equals

Answer (score 10):

`First()` method works properly. But you'll remove the `First()` sorted item.

```
SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>();
set.Add("b");
set.Add("c");
set.Add("a");
Console.WriteLine(set.First()); // Display 'A'
set.Remove(set.First()); // Remove 'A'
Console.WriteLine(set.First()); // Display 'B'
```

Comment: Instead of First, you can use Min.

Comment: Min will be significantly faster - both will do a logN tree descent, but First allocates an intermediate enumerator.

Answer (score 8):

This is pretty straight forward, e.g.

```
SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>();
set.Add("Hi");
var f = set.First();
set.Remove(f);
```

Comment: my code is exatly the same except I got other class, not string.

Comment: @BogdanFichitiu The same principle applies.  If you post your code, and explain the manner in which it "doesn't work", then it's easier for us to spot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SortedSet<T>.Remove` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395032.aspx) and [`Enumerable.First<TSource>` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx)

> Removes a specified item from the `SortedSet<T>`.

and

> Returns the first element of a sequence.

```
SortedSet<string> s = new SortedSet<string>();
...
s.Remove(s.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

First() doesn't remove anything. You aren't popping it off a stack. If you want to remove it after you take it.

```
 var coll =....your sorted set
 var p = coll.First();
 coll.remove(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SortedSet.Remove() See [this link for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395032.aspx)

See [this link for some nice sortedset examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sortedset)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove element by calling First(). First() Extension method just returns a reference to the first element. In order to remove item you need to call [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395032.aspx).

Comment: George Johnston already answered things that you have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Working example using Console app

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>();
        set.Add("One");
        set.Add("Two");
        set.Add("Three");

        string first = set.First();
        set.Remove(first);

        foreach (var s in set)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);                
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```